# Could the S of S.O.L.I.D be extended for every single element of the code?

Tags: c++, oop, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

The S of the famous Object Oriented Programming design stands for:

> Single responsibility principle, the notion that an object should have
>   only a single responsibility.

I was wondering, can this principle, be extended even to arrays, variables, and all the elements of a program?

For example, let's say we have:

```
int A[100];
```

And we use it to store the result of a function, but somehow we use the same A[100] to check, for example, what indexes of A have we already checked and elaborated.
Could this be considered wrong? Shouldn't we create another element to store, for example, the indexes that we have already checked? Isn't this an hint of future messy code?

PS: I'm sorry if my question is not comprehensible but English is not my primary language. If you have any problem understanding the point of it please let me know in a comment below.

Comment: when at one point a variable means one thing, and at another point the exact same variable means a totally different thing, both with the same value, then certainly something is wrong, no matter if you name it after that principle or not.

Comment: Responsibility is not always equivalent to meaning.  As i remember it, "responsibility" is semi-defined as "reason to change".  Is `A[x]` ever going to change for a reason that doesn't involve calling your function and storing the result?

Comment: @cHao, No, probably not. But let's think that in a year from now, someone wants to implement something else using that array. Isn't it hard to deal with a single array that is used for two different jobs?

Comment: @JeffPigarelli: Sure, but let's think that in another year, someone's going to want to implement something else.  And 6 months later, something else.  And so on, til you have a dozen separate-but-not-really arrays of flags or whatever, whereas a single array of objects would have been a much cleaner and more extensible choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If same `A` instance is used in different program code portions you *must* follow this principle. If `A` is a auxiliary variable, local one for example, I think *you don't need* to be care about it.

Comment: Ok, but then where's the line that divide an auxiliary variable from a normal one? It seems to me that your behavior is something like "let's get lazy if we work at the lowest level of our application".

Comment: @JeffPigarelli Of course not. For me, lowest level has the same problems that business level. You are trying to grow this principle to all program variables and this is not viable. This is not a OOP principle, is a programming principle. Never mix variable meanings. For me, an auxiliary variable, I suppose you think the same, is a restricted scope variable. If not, don't change its meaning in different code portions.

Comment: Is there a specific design elaborated to define the "Never mix variable meanings" principle?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe OOP itself and common sense. If you have any doubt about a variable mixed meaning, just create a new one and use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are tracking the use of bits of the array that have been updated, then you probably shouldn't be using an array, but a map instead.

In any case, if you need that sort of extra control over the array, then basically, you should be considering a class that contains both the contents of the array and the various information about what has and hasn't been done. So your array becomes local to the class object, as do your controls, and voila. You have single responsibility again.

Comment: That was about a university test I've attended. We haven't studied maps or classes yet. The code was all inside the `int main() {}`.

Comment: I would say if the code was all inside int main(), the 'S' part was already broken beyond hope of recovery